# Uniform balancing with AWS network load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

We have several servers behind an AWS network load balancer.
The used algorithm for balancing trafic is the "round robin" describe as below :
"With Network Load Balancers, the load balancer node that receives the connection uses the following process:

```
Selects a target from the target group for the default rule using a flow hash algorithm. It bases the algorithm on:

    The protocol

    The source IP address and source port

    The destination IP address and destination port

    The TCP sequence number

Routes each individual TCP connection to a single target for the life of the connection. 
The TCP connections from a client have different source ports and sequence numbers, and can be routed to different targets."
```

Due to the persistance of connections, servers load may be unbalanced and can cause problems.

How to configure the network load balancer to route new connections on the server that have the less load ?

Answer (score 2):

ALBs now support [Least Outstanding Request](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/application-load-balancer-now-supports-least-outstanding-requests-algorithm-for-load-balancing-requests/) routing.  NLB does not appear to support this (yet?)

Is there any possibility of adapting your LB strategy to ALBs from NLBs?

Comment: No, I can't. The traffic is pure TCP/IP, that is not supported by ALB...

Comment: @JeremDem then your best bet is to replace the NLB with an Envoy or Nginx+ loadbalancer with configuration that you can control.  NLB cannot do what you need.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help ! I will analyse this solution. :)